# How to use in "this" first collection with class?

Tags: jquery

I have jquery selection:

```
 $('.interesting-textarea, .check-select, .bold-interesting, .border-interesting')
```

Question is: How to use in "this" first collection with class ".check-select", such:

```
$('.interesting-textarea, .check-select, .bold-interesting, .border-
interesting').on("click", function() {
    $(this).get(1).val();
});
```

Comment: Explain what do you think `$(this).get(1)` is supposed to do

Comment: Take collection with number "1" from selection

Comment: What "collection" means? What do you think `this` equals to in your code? Have you tried to check it?

Comment: Only elements with class ".check-select", for example. I need to use their values soon in this script. But script fire on click for all elements.

Comment: right. It's the one clicked element only. Now let's go further - do you know what `.get()` method returns? Why type is the returned result?

Comment: .get() - Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object. In my case jQuery object-$('.interesting-textarea, .check-select, .bold-interesting, .border-
interesting'). I need one element with calss from this object, and get value of it for ajaxSubmit.

Comment: right. So you now realize that DOM element doesn't have `.val()` element, don't you? "I need one element" --- `this` always refers to one element only (in this case). So `$(this).get(0)` is identical to `this`

Comment: I know that get().val() - isn't working. So i ask this quetion: How to get value of this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
$('.interesting-textarea, .check-select, .bold-interesting, .border-
interesting').on("click", function() {
     if($(this).is('.check-select')){
        //only for this selector
     }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/csy6b/

Demo2 : http://jsfiddle.net/csy6b/1/

Comment: Thank you. But i need to take .val() of this element.

Comment: you can use it inside the `if` statement as `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code will fail since `$(this).get(1)` returns the actual JS object and not a jquery one so it has no val() method.
2. In order to get what you need do this:

   ```
    $('.interesting-textarea, .check-select, .bold-interesting, .border-
     interesting').on("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass('check-select')){
        //Do whatever you want
      }
    });
   ```

Comment: 1. I know. Therefore it is not suitable fo me. 2. And how to take value of object with class ".check-select"? Thank for your time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$(this).context.className;
```

which will return the `className` of the clicked element.